# How to share services and state between ngModules

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

1. How do we share state using **ngrx** between ngModules?
2. How do we share the same service instance between ngModules?

**Angular2-RC5.**

Comment: What do you mean by between modules? modules or components?

Comment: He means `@NgModule` just like he said. It's a valid question, i'm trying to figure that out my self, but i'm afraid the only solution for now is to just cram everything in to the root module. I think we need to wait for ngrx effects to update to RC5.

Comment: @Filip Lauc Thanks for the clarification. Maby other liberies like ng2-redux can solve this problem?

Comment: They might. But i think i'd rather wait for ngrx to update then switch to a new library all together.

Answer (score 6):

The modules need to have the same instance of the service.  To accomplish this, the service needs to be in the `providers` of your bootsrap `AppModule` only. Otherwise, if the same service is found in different providers, you could be running parallel instances.

So the question becomes: how to get the service in the top-level `providers`, but exclude it from all other modules?

**With a service you write yourself**, it's really straightforward.

- If the service is part of `AppModule`, pt it in that module's `providers` and nowhere else
- If the service is in another module (let's call it `DummyModule`) of yours that you're importing into other modules, make sure to *not* put it in `DummyModule`'s `providers` or an Angular injector will create a parallel instance of it for every lazy-loaded module that imports `DummyModule`.  Instead, you want to expose that service from a `forRoot()` static method.

So change:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [ MyService]
})
export class DummyModule{ }
```

To:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [] //empty since we want a singleton service
})
export class DummyModule{
  static forRoot() {
    return {ngModule: DummyModule, providers: [ MyService ]};
  }
}
```

Now when regular modules `imports: [DummyModule]`, they will not get `MyService`. On the other hand, in `AppModule`, you have `imports: [DummyModule.forRoot()]` which exposes the service. As a result, only the top-most component gets the service and you'll have a single instance of it shared among all modules.

**With a 3rd party service**, it's not straightforward.

Basically, you need the 3rd party developer to make the change above if it's also using `@NgModule`. Alternatively, instead of importing the 3rd party module, you can create a custom module that declares that module's components, pipes and directives, but implements the change above to put that module's services in a `forRoot()` method.

This is what I did to get a 3rd party service -- `MdIconService` (part of an Angular Material module) -- to work as a single instance even though its module isn't yet configured properly. [See this github issue.](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1071)

Comment: Okay, I have read all the info on modules on angular2 web and now I understand what you wrote and its very nice solution. I can't accept this answer becouse I still dont understand how to share reducers that declared in diffrent modules. (or there will be no solution to that and we have to do it one time at the app module (thats sucks)). Thanks!

Comment: Just to confirm, about a year later, this is indeed an approach advocated by ngrx 4. In its sample app (a part of the platform repo) there is a module like DummyModule above - it is called AuthModule. See https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/example-app/app/auth/auth.module.ts